# What is the Domain of $f(x) = x^{1/x}$

Tags: functions, exponential-function, exponentiation

looking on wolphram alpha for the function
$$f(x) = x^{1/x}$$
it says that the domain is
for each $x>0$ but for example if I make $x=-3$ it becomes
$$   (-3)^{1/(-3)} = \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^{1/3} = -0.69336....  $$

So where am I wrong? [image]

Comment: Part of it has to do with how you define a fractional exponent of a negative number.  What do you suppose would be $(-0.5)^{-0.5}$?  Would it be real?  Would it be imaginary?  Recall that there are $n$ different $n$'th roots of a number.  If you want to talk about this as a function, which one of those $n$ roots would you take?  The real one if it exists?  The one with smallest argument?  You're running into complex territory here.

Comment: yes assuming all available in R. If is not in R then its not in the domain

Comment: You completely missed the point of my questions.  Read it again.

Comment: @JMoravitz yes, i agree that is not part of the domain when x is an even number, but when it is an odd number it's part of the domain right?

Comment: Not necessarily.  There are those who prefer to say that $\sqrt[3]{-1}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$ for instance.  It depends on how you define things... and *you haven't yet defined things*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a real function, $x^y$ is defined as
$$x^y\overset{\text{def}}{=}\mathrm e^{y\ln x}, \enspace\text{ so }\quad x^{\tfrac 1x}=
\mathrm e^{\tfrac{\ln x}x},$$
which requires $x>0$ to be defined.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) =x^{\frac{1}{x}} =e^{\frac{1}{x} \ln(x)} $

So  :

The Domain  is $ ] 0,+\infty [$

Because the domain of $ \ln(x) $ is $ ] 0,+\infty [$

And  the domain of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\mathbb{R^*} $

And the domain of $e $ is $\mathbb{R} $

Answer (score -1):

Its

$$(-3)^{1/(-3)}$$

not

$$-(3^{1/(-3)})$$

Comment: The argument can be made that $(-a)^{1/3} = (-1)^{1/3}(a)^{1/3}=-(a)^{1/3}$ if people ignore the ambiguity of principle roots and what not.  It is conceivable that the manipulation done here was not only intentional, but possibly correct under certain sets of definitions.  This is not the issue here, but rather, the issue is the difficulty of taking arbitrary noninteger powers of negative numbers which requires more care to define which this answer does nothing to address.